# Why can't an exponential family have Gamma(X) as a sufficient statistic?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

**Background** The paper referenced below at one point makes an argument that goes something like this:

Let $X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$, where $\text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta)$ refers to the Gamma distribution with shape $\alpha$ and rate $\beta$.
The log pdf is given by

\begin{align*}
 \log p(x \, | \, \alpha, \beta) = \alpha \log \beta - \ln \Gamma(\alpha) - (\alpha -1 ) x - \beta x 
\end{align*}
Suppose we want to find a (semi-)conjugate prior for the shape parameter $\alpha$.  Considering the log pdf  as a function of $\alpha$, the prior must have sufficient statistics that are linear combinations of $(\alpha, \Gamma(\alpha)).$ But there is
no exponential family distribution with density on $\alpha$ whose sufficient statistics include $\Gamma(\alpha)$ as a basis function.

**Question**
Why can't $\Gamma(\alpha)$ be one of the sufficient statistics for an exponential family distribution?

**Reference**
Winn, J., Bishop, C. M., & Jaakkola, T. (2005). Variational message passing. Journal of Machine Learning Research, 6(4).

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't Γ(α) be one of the sufficient statistics for an exponential family distribution?

Gamma distribution, member of the exponential family can be written as

$$f_X(x,\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\text{exp}\left\{(\alpha-1)\log x-x\beta   \right\}$$

thus

$$T=\left(\sum_i \log x_i; \sum_i x_i\right)$$

is jointly sufficient for $\theta=(\alpha;\beta)$

---

> Suppose we want to find a (semi-)conjugate prior for the shape parameter α.

...let's suppose $\beta$ is known.

The gamma model can be factorize as follows

$$p(\mathbf{x},\alpha)=  e^{-\beta\Sigma x}\times\frac{\beta^{n \alpha}}{\left[\Gamma(\alpha)\right]^n}\prod_x x^{\alpha-1}=\psi(\mathbf{x})\times g(t(\mathbf{x}),n,\alpha)$$

thus the conjugate prior will have the form as

$$\pi(\alpha)\propto g(s,m,\alpha)$$

that is

$$\pi(\alpha)\propto \frac{c^{m\alpha}}{\left[\Gamma(\alpha)\right]^m}s^{\alpha-1}$$

...if $\beta$ is unknown too, use the same procedure to find the requested prior

---

FYK, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) find an useful link with a table of the major statistical models with all the detailed priors, posterior's parameters and so on

Comment: I appreciate your response!   But I think that none of that answers my question.  

You have a form for what the density of the prior on alpha must be.   The claim (from the paper) is that that density *cannot* be the density of an exponential family distribution.  Why not?

Comment: That is, the problematic term is $\Gamma(a)$.  $\textit{Why?}$